# Show that $ \lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}\frac{2^{\sqrt{\log(x)}}}{\sqrt{x}} = 0 $

Tags: limits, derivatives, logarithms, computational-complexity, limits-without-lhopital

I am trying to prove that 
$$
\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}\frac{2^{\sqrt{\log(x)}}}{\sqrt{x}} = 0
$$

However, derivatives for using L'Hopital look really horrific. 
How can I prove the result?

Comment: Hint: Let $x=e^{u^2}$ and note that $2^u=e^{u\log2}$.

Comment: Thank you :) Got it!